# Difference between *argv[index] (char**) and argv[index] (char*) passed to isdigit(int)

Tags: c

Suppose we have

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]{...}
```

For which reason the

```
if(isdigit(*argv[index])){...}
```

with index being just an int, works but the

```
if(isdigit(argv[index])){...}
```

isn't working and tells that can't convert `char*` (which is the `argv[index]`) to `int` which is the argument that isdigit wants to be passed into? How the compiler recognized `char**` as an `int` and `char*` as not an `int`?

Comment: What? `argv` is `char **`. `argv[index]` is `char *` (aka string). `*argv[index]` is a `char`.

Comment: Are you confusing `*` and `&`?

Comment: This is the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you have not posted the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isdigit(*argv[index])){...}
```

`argv` is `char **`, so `*argv[index]` is just `char` type, which can be converted to `int` implicitly.

But `argv[index]` is `char *` type, to convert to `int`, you need to convert explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

isdigit requires a char parameter, not a char*, argv is an array of char *, therefore argv[index] leaves you with a char *. Your options are *argv[index] (as you discovered) or argv[index][0].